# Which component do you use to render RichText field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, form, rich-text, richhtmlfield

Which component (from which package) do you use to build rich text editor **with** support for table creation for your SPFx projects?

So far I found "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/RichText" but it doesn't have support for table creation

Comment: Hi, does my below answer help in you in any way? If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill) component which does have support for table as well.

You can find samples at below link:

- [React Quill Examples and Templates](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-quill)
- [React-Quill example with table](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-luctk)

Hope it will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

To add table creation support to your rich text editor, you can consider using additional third-party libraries or components.

As mentioned by @Jitendra in his response above, you can use the `react-quill` library, which provides a rich text editor component with extensive features, including table creation capabilities.

To use `react-quill` in your SPFx project, you'll need to install the necessary dependencies. Here are the steps:

1. Install the required packages by running the following command in your SPFx project's root directory:

   ```
   npm install react-quill quill
   ```
2. Import the necessary modules in your component file:

   ```
   import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
   import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';
   ```
3. Use the `ReactQuill` component in your code, providing appropriate props and configuring it to enable table creation:

   ```
   <ReactQuill
     value={this.state.editorContent}
     onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
     modules={{
       toolbar: {
         container: [
           [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
           ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote'],
           [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
           ['link', 'image', 'video'],
           ['table'], // Add table button to the toolbar
           ['clean'],
         ],
       },
       clipboard: {
         matchVisual: false,
       },
     }}
     formats={[
       'header',
       'bold',
       'italic',
       'underline',
       'strike',
       'blockquote',
       'list',
       'bullet',
       'link',
       'image',
       'video',
       'table', // Enable table format
     ]}
   />
   ```

With the `react-quill` library, you can leverage the `table` format option and the table button in the toolbar configuration to enable table creation within your rich text editor.

You can refer to the following article for a detailed example and code implementation: [Rich Text Control in SPFx using React-Quill](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/rich-text-control-in-spfx-using-react-quill/).

**Source**:  [Rich Text Control in SPFx using React-Quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76382679/sharepoint-spfx-which-component-do-you-use-to-render-richtext-field)

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?